# PHP parent/child categories

Tags: php, parsing, tree

Have the data below in a table:

```
programgroup,programcode
"C1","AM"
"C1","CC"
"C1","CC"
"C1","CC"
"C1","CC"
"C1","CC"
"C1","CC"
"C1","CP"
"C1","CP"
"C1","CP"
"C1","CP"
"C1","PL"
"C1","PL"
"C1","PL"
"C1","PL"
"C1","PL"
"C4","2IC"
"C4","2IC"
"C4","2IC"
"C4","2IC"
"C4","2IC"
"C4","AO"
"C4","AO"
"C4","AO"
"C4","IP"
"C4","IP"
"C4","PA"
"C4","PA"
"C4","PM"
"C4","PR"
"C4","PR"
"C4","SR"
"C4","WH3"
```

I'm reading the data and iterating over the records and  I need to insert a category in a table for each ProgramGroup and a child category for each ProgramCode that has a parent_id of the category for the ProgramGroup it is contained in, i.e. (MAIN category will already exist)

```
category_id, value, parent_id
0,  "MAIN", null
1,  "C1",  0
2,  "AM",  1
3,  "CC",  1
4,  "CP",  1
5,  "PL",  1
6,  "C4",  0
7,  "21C", 6
8,  "AO",  6
9,  "IP",  6
10, "PA",  6
11, "PM",  6
12, "PR",  6
13, "SR",  6
14, "WH3", 6
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this in PHP pseudo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your main array is in an array variable we will call `$programs` AND that `category_id` is an auto increment column:

```
$program_groups = array_keys($programs);    // will store as array([0] => C1, [1] => C4)
$program_codes = array_unique($programs);   // will store as array([0] => AM, [1] => CC, [7] => CP, .. )

foreach($program_groups as $index => $key) {  
  // INSERT INTO table (category_id, value, parent_id) VALUES ($index, $key, '0');  
}  

foreach($program_codes as $index => $value) {  
  $parent_id = array_search($programs, $index);  
  //  INSERT INTO table (value, parent_id) VALUES ($value, $parent_id);  
}
```

But really I would look for other ways to optimize your original setup, if at all possible.  This setup doesn't seem natural.